# I implemented a Map object in C, but using it gives me a Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Below, I've defined a `Map` struct in C.  It functions as a map, with `setValue` and `getValue` functions.  Key values default to -1.

```
typedef struct {
    int key;
    int value;
} Index;

typedef Index Map[1000];



void initMap(Map *map)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Index thisIndex = *map[i];
        thisIndex.key = -1;
        thisIndex.value = 0;
    }
}

int getValue(Map *map, int keyToGet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Index thisIndex = *map[i];
        if (thisIndex.key == keyToGet)
        {
            return thisIndex.value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void setValue(Map *map, int keyToSet, int valueToSet)
{
    int set = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Index thisIndex = *map[i];
        if (thisIndex.key == keyToSet)
        {
            thisIndex.value = valueToSet;
            set = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (set == 1)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Index thisIndex = *map[i];
        if (thisIndex.key == -1)
        {
            thisIndex.key = keyToSet;
            thisIndex.value = valueToSet;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int findValue(Map *map, int valueToGet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Index thisIndex = *map[i];
        if (thisIndex.value == valueToGet)
            return thisIndex.key;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

At some point in the code, when run, I get a SegFault, presumably for accessing or trying to write over memory over which I do not have jurisdiction.  My question is, where is that happening?  Which function could be doing that, and where?  I've sifted through multiple times and I can't seem to find where that would be happening.

Comment: Finding errors from just reading code is exceptionally difficult. You wrote it, and even you can't! Instead of asking others to do this very hard task, you should use a better tool than simply going over the code. Use a debugger.

Comment: I'm relatively new to C, and don't know exactly how I'd go about doing that.  Can you point me in a direction?  I'm using gcc as my compiler, on MacOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Something tells me `*map[i]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I agree with StoryTeller. A debugger not only tells you errors in your coding, it often also reveals errors in your thinking. It is _the_ most important tool in realizing faultless and flawless code.

Comment: If you compile with GCC, than you may use [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Okay, I'll look into gdb a bit and see if I can't sort this out myself.  Thank you!

Comment: If you're on Linux, the fastest way to find out what's wrong is to install valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) and just do `valgrind ./your_executable`. It will tell you the answer straight away.

Comment: I have never understood professor's enmity toward debuggers, they make so much more sence in most cases than pouring over traces.

Comment: Since Map is an array, you probably don't want to pass a pointer to Map into functions--just pass a Map, then you can index it without dereferencing (i.e, no need for `(*map)[x]`)

Comment: `typedef`ing an array is usually wrong.  better to have a typedef for the one instance, then the code declares an instance of an array of the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major errors in your code.

First, you typedef `Map` to an array. That means when you have a function prototype like this:

```
int getValue(Map *map, int keyToGet);
```

you really get something like this:

```
int getValue(Index (*map)[1000], int keyToGet);
```

In C, definition mimicks use, so you should access your map elements like this:

```
Index thisIndex = (*map)[i];
```

Your way to use it, `*map[i]` is equivalent to *(map[i]) and requires the array to be an array of 1,000 pointers to `Index`, which it isn't.

The `(*map)[i]`sytnax complicated, and you don't need it. Because your `Map` is an array, it decays into a pointer to its first element. You do not need to pass a pointer to an array if you want to modify the elements. It is enough to pass a pointer to the first element, which in your case can be either of:

```
int getValue(Map map, int keyToGet);
int getValue(Index map[], int keyToGet);
int getValue(Index *map, int keyToGet);
```

Accessing the elements of the array is then just `map[i]`.

Fixing that fixes your segmentation fault, but it doesn't fix the fact that your map doesn't work. When you assign to a struct like this:

```
Index thisIndex = map[i];
```

and then modify `thisIndex`, you will not modify anything in your `map`! Here, `thisIndex` is a copy. When `thisIndex` goes out of scope, all modifications are lost.

You can either use the `map` directly:

```
if (map[i].key == keyToSet) {
    map[i].value = valueToSet;
    return;
}
```

(and why don't you? `thisIndex` is longer than `map[i]`), or you can make `thisIndex` a pointer to the array element:

```
Index *thisIndex = &map[i];

if (thisIndex->key == keyToSet) {
    thisIndex->value = valueToSet;
    return;
}
```

Here, you access and modify the fields of `map[i]` through the pointer.

Hiding an array in a typedef is probably not such a good idea. Perhaps at one time you want to keep the number of active items alongside the array. (That would make your code more efficient, because you wouldn't have to traverse all 1,000 items in the worst case.) In that case, you could make `Map` a struct with an array of 1000 key/value pairs and a count. Then you would have to pass pointers to the struct type, so that you can update the fields. This is left as an exercise ... `:)`